# Is there a predefined variable for "/home/vsts" in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to cache files in `/home/vsts/.cache/torch/`.

Is there a predefined variable for the home folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "Predefined variables" you mean one of the variables specified in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) then no.

However if you are using Hosted Linux Agents you can simply look at the environment variable `$HOME`, which works at least if you are in a script:, which may or may not fit your use case.

Example:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - script: echo $HOME
```

The output of the script task is `/home/vsts`

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no such variable. You can use one of the `/home/vsts/work` paths and cache `$(System.WorkFolder)/../.cache/torch/`.

Values of predefined variables for an Ubuntu agent:

```
Agent.AcceptTeeEula             True              
Agent.BuildDirectory            /home/vsts/work/1               
Agent.HomeDirectory             /home/vsts/agents/2.181.2              
Agent.Id                        32   
Agent.JobName                   Job        
Agent.JobStatus                 Succeeded          
Agent.MachineName               fv-az160-540            
Agent.Name                      Azure Pipelines 2     
Agent.OS                        Linux   
Agent.OSArchitecture            X64               
Agent.RetainDefaultEncoding     false                      
Agent.ReadOnlyVariables         true                  
Agent.RootDirectory             /home/vsts/work              
Agent.TempDirectory             /home/vsts/work/_temp              
Agent.ToolsDirectory            /opt/hostedtoolcache               
Agent.Version                   2.181.2        
Agent.WorkFolder                /home/vsts/work           
Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory  /home/vsts/work/1/a                         
Build.BinariesDirectory         /home/vsts/work/1/b                  
Build.DefinitionName            FooBar
Build.SourceBranch              refs/heads/FOOBAR-123-caching
Build.SourceVersion             2b2c45223722fc7226eb23d752fc722bcdee2c54
Build.SourcesDirectory          /home/vsts/work/1/s                 
Build.StagingDirectory          /home/vsts/work/1/a                 
Common.TestResultsDirectory     /home/vsts/work/1/TestResults                      
Pipeline.Workspace              /home/vsts/work/1             
System.AccessToken              ***             
System.ArtifactsDirectory       /home/vsts/work/1/a                    
System.CollectionId             c02d3c7b-9d74-4532-aa21-abccdf07c888
System.Culture                  en-US         
System.DefaultWorkingDirectory  /home/vsts/work/1/s                         
System.DefinitionId             26              
System.EnableAccessToken        SecretVariable                   
System.HostType                 build          
System.JobAttempt               1            
System.JobId                    33f11733-54f2-5aa3-20dd-22fc7dcf5912
System.JobName                  __default         
System.PhaseAttempt             1              
System.PhaseDisplayName         Job                  
System.PhaseName                Job           
System.ServerType               Hosted            
System.StageAttempt             1              
System.StageName                __default           
System.TeamProject              Foo Bar
System.TeamProjectId            3337a4f6-1411-40aa-beeb-0c7d86b9ecba
System.WorkFolder               /home/vsts/work            
Task.DisplayName                print predefined variables
```